# How to change the response function name in Zend Soap Server?

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework, wsdl

I'm generating a WSDL and I need to change the function name in the response to match the name from the client (which I have no control over).

Here's the WSDL response I'm getting:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:8000/soap/index.php?wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:fooFunctionResponse>
         <return xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</return>
      </ns1:fooFunctionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need the line `<ns1:fooFunctionResponse>` to read `<ns1:fooFunctionAcknowledgement>`.

Here is my Soap server:

```
if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
     $soapAutoDiscover = new \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());
     $soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
     $soapAutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
     $soapAutoDiscover->setClass('SoapFunction');
     $soapAutoDiscover->setUri(http://localhost:8000/soap/index.php);
     $soapAutoDiscover->handle();
} else {
    $soap = new \Zend\Soap\Server(null, array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2, 'uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/soap/index.php?wsdl',  'classmap' => array('Identification', 'RemoteIdentification')));
    $soap->setClass('SoapFunction');
    $soap->handle();
}
```

I've found this line of code in the Zend framework (`Autodiscover.php` line 514) which looks like it controls the naming of the function:

```
$element = [
    'name'      => $functionName . 'Response',
    'sequence'  => $sequence
];
```

<del>But changing it does nothing at all, the parent method is never called. I've no idea how to solve this problem, please help.</del>

**I've discovered that this line does change the function name, however I'm using SoapUI to test my API, and from SoapUI I *always* see `Response` instead of whatever I change the string to. In Chrome, I see `Acknowledgement`.**

Why does SoapUI show a different function name?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Zend Framework and/or it's structure. But I think you can simply extend the class containing the `response()` method and overwrite the method.

```
// Example Zend Class
class Zend_Class {

    public function response()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Your own Class
class Own_Class extends Zend_Class
{
    public function ResponseBoohoo()
    {
        return parent::response();
    }
}
```

If I totally and utterly misunderstood you, I apologize. :)

Comment: I would do that if I was sure that the method containing the `response()` was being called. As far as I know that method is not called.

Comment: I've just checked and seen that the method is called, but SoapUI is doing some strange things, see my edit.